# What is this white spots inside my Bialetti Moka?

Tags: moka

What is this white spots inside my Bialetti Moka, and they appear even after clean it.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is corrosion of the metal depending on what is put in that container and the chemical properties of that substance can lead to wear and tear on the metal. Test this out to see if this works mix a baking soda solution and let it soak in the pot for 30 min to an hour. Then wash the pot that should remove it.